# adding charcter before and after a regular link in hover state

Tags: html, css

wondering if it's possible to add a character right before and after the link text in a hover state.

For example

regular state:

"The Text"

Hover state:

"[ The Text ]"

As it is at the moment my list looks like this.

```
<div  id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Journalist</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Writer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Publications designer</a></li>
</ul>

#navigation li a:hover{


  text-shadow:2px 1px 3px #00CDCD;}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use generated content:

```
a:hover::before {
    content: '[ ';
}

a:hover::after {
    content: ' ]';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ArySE/).